# R' Akiva Eiger and the epidemic

Tags: health-safety-shmira, dina-dmalchusa-dina, rav-akiva-eiger

A rav mentioned it to me that [R' Akiva Eiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akiva_Eger) got an award from the Prussian king, because during an epidemic in [Posen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pozna%C5%84) he, in accordance with the doctors and the authorities, required the strict observance of the anti-epidemic regulations. I have found the [story on the internet](https://www.jewishpress.com/kidz/tales-of-the-gaonim/rav-akiva-eiger/2011/11/25/2/), yet I would be curious, what did he write about this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

R. Akiva Eger’s letter regarding the cholera epidemic of 1831 can be seen in [Iggerot Soferim, 29](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44152&st=&pgnum=53).

You can see a translation of a slightly different version of the letter [here](https://rabbidunner.com/a-distinguished-rabbi-responds-to-the-threat-of-a-pandemic-in-1831/).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact You have to click "next" in the top left to get to the next page

Comment: @ba Aha. But that (a) isn't really obvious on the page and (b) I didn't even notice anything on the page because the link is causing an immediate download of the first page as a PDF. There is a link on the translation page for the full PDF - I'll add that to the original answer.