# Epidemics and public torah study

Tags: halacha, torah-study, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, health-safety-shmira, responsa

In the current pandemic, there seem to be diverse opinions, both of medical/government officials and of religious leaders regarding communal gatherings for religious services.  For example, some shuls and schools have been closed entirely, while others have imposed limitations regarding the number and spacing of congregating worshippers and students.

What historical halachic rulings and/or responsa are there from past contagious epidemics/pandemics, such as the cholera epidemic of 1831, regarding maintaining or limiting torah study in Yeshivot (of adolescents and/or adults) as well as that of *tinokot shel beit raban* (children's schools)?

Related (regarding prayer): [R' Akiva Eiger and the epidemic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/112044/r-akiva-eiger-and-the-epidemic)

Comment: These historical rulings may be interesting, but they are unlikely to help you sort through these allegedly "diverse opinions". Every location and every pathogen is different. It's no surprise that different situations warrant different rulings.

Comment: Don't study Torah publicly. The Torah will not [protect](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2020/03/who-really-believes-that-torah-protects.html) you from coronavirus.